# Rails 5 cipher.key "key must be 32 bytes" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Brand new Rails application.

Rails version 5.0.0.1, Ruby version 2.4.0preview2.

Create application "demo", run a simple scaffold generate Product, and get an error when trying to view the scaffold's overview page (base index file still loads the Welcome to Rails screen fine):

ArgumentError in ProductsController#index
key must be 32 bytes:

```
  cipher = new_cipher
  cipher.encrypt
  cipher.key = @secret

  # Rely on OpenSSL for the initialization vector
  iv = cipher.random_iv
```

The problem line is apparently cipher.key = @secret.

I've seen various mentions on the github repo for Rails mentioning this issue, but all implied it was now resolved in Rails 5.0.0.1

Comment: Are you *sure* about being on `5.0.0.1`, not `5.0.0.0`? I've just been reading through [this issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25185) and the associated pull requests; it looks like the bug has been fixed? I'll try to recreate it as you describe, though...

Comment: If I run `rails -v` I get `Rails 5.0.0.1`, and running `gem list rails -all` shows just 5.0.0.1 installed

Comment: Gemfile lists `gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0', '>= 5.0.0.1'`

Answer (score 11):

Ok, there was a slight misunderstanding on my part, looks like the fix is coming in 5.0.1 not 5.0.0.1

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/26694

Comment: Can confirm that updating to 5.0.1 did fix this issue

Comment: @Aaron Confirmed

Answer (score 3):

Please use **Digest::MD5** to achive 32 bytes

```
require 'openssl'
require 'digest'
require 'base64'

data = "encrypt me"
secret_key = "asd3dssdf34HDas"
c = OpenSSL::Cipher.new("aes-256-cbc")
c.encrypt
c.key = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(secret_key) # this will convert key length into 32
encrypted_data = c.update(data.to_s) + c.final
encrypted_data = Base64.urlsafe_encode64(encrypted_data, padding: false) #padding: false will remove '/', '+' from encrypted data
encrypted_data.gsub! "\n",""
```

Or Simply use **secret key** of length 32 bytes

```
data = "encrypt me"
secret_key = "Aswertyuioasdfghjkqwertyuiqwerty"
c = OpenSSL::Cipher.new("aes-256-cbc")
c.encrypt
c.key = secret_key 
encrypted_data = c.update(data.to_s) + c.final
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally found problem! It was from a bugfix... https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12561

If you are using cipher e.g. 'aes-256-cfb', the `key_len` is 32, found by:

```
require 'openssl'
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('aes-256-cfb')
cipher.key_len # => 32
```

We had mistakenly thought we needed to send a 256 character nonce, but actually you are supposed to send a 32 character nonce - or
 use `cipher.random_key` (which internally uses the `key_len`). It never used to be a problem because openssl truncated the nonce... but now you need to send the right lengthed nonce.

We got this error upgrading ruby from 2.3.4 to 2.4.2.

Answer (score 2):

This issue turns out to be connected to the key you are using. Without changing your key you can use the code below to transform your key to 32 bytes:

> attr_encrypted :attribute, key: ENV['MY_KEY'].bytes[0..31].pack( "c" * 32 )

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

then, the most important thing:

```
bundle update
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use `random_key` so it always fit.

```
key = cipher.random_key
cipher.key = key
```

reference http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Cipher.html

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**:

1. Edit your Gemfile
2. Add the following line: gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0', '>= 5.0.0.1'
3. bundle install
4. Optional: I am using ruby2-4.1 . (rvm install ruby-2.4.1)

**Rational**: The rails version prior to 5.0.0 seems to have a bug that causes this issue. The bug has been resolved in the latest version of Rails.  If you hare following the Rails Installation Guide (http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-mac.html) you will probably encounter this problem as of this posting date.

This fix does work, and is verified by

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem too and fixed it by running

```
bundle update
```

Make sure that you have the latest version of rails installed.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error:
Running bundle update should do the trick